# Конкатенация строк в PostgreSQL с условием

Tags: postgresql, concat

Имеется таблица с информацией о сотрудниках, содержащая колонки: house_number, building_structure, apartment.
Необходимо в запроcе select объединить значения этих полей в строку "адрес".
я попытался использовать следующую конструкцию:
CONCAT('д.', house_number,' корп.',building_structure , ' кв. ', apartment) AS Адрес, Если значения в колонках, не пустые, то всё выводится корректно (д.1 корп.2 кв.12) но если значение в колонках пустые (empty_string) то в результате выводится: д.1 корпус.кв.
Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно составить запрос, что бы при отсутствии значения в одной из колонок не выводился префикс? например д.1 и всё или д.1 кв.12 при отсутствии значения корпус в колонке building_structure.

p.s. Сервер PostgreSQL 12

Comment: Ну, самое простое, но замутное - сделать через `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END`. Наверняка есть специальная функция, с помощью которой можно сделать проще, но я так сразу не соображу.

Comment: `CONCAT('д.' || house_number, ' корп.' || building_structure , ' кв. ' || apartment)`

Comment: Так, тоже пробовал, к сожалению работает так же как и в моем случае

Comment: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/n9sDm_4R). Попробуй ещё, только на этот раз руками.

Comment: @Akina, немного уточнить нужно, оказывается в ячейках не null а empty_string (база не моя, доступна только для чтения). Если в вашем примере заменить NULL на empty_string то отрабатывает некорректно, так же как и в моем случае.

Comment: *оказывается в ячейках не null а empty_string* Тогда дополнительно обернуть поля в NULLIF().  Или, как советовал @CrazyElf, использовать CASE.

Comment: @Akina А, ну вот через `NULLIF` оказалось гораздо короче )

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо всем за идеи, правильное решение выглядит следующим образом:

```
CONCAT('д.' || NULLIF(house_number,''), ' корп.' || NULLIF(building_structure,''), ' кв. ' || NULLIF(apartment,''))
```